# how to get parse relation data

Tags: android, parse-platform, parse-android-sdk

I am new to parse with android I am having query that brings all data of a class as `object`. and there is another class with two relation columns every time I get the relation table a new `query` is fired in that case if there are too many rows in that table the `query` will be fired with that much amount which will effect my response time. So I need a `query` that can return the data of parent table.

Comment: Can you share code , Please

Answer (score 0):

I was using Parse Relations by which it is not possible to fetch the data of the parse sub classes so i gave a try to Parse pointer and was able to fetch the results.
Please go through the link for better understanding.

[[Parse - Using relations versus pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23459111/parse-using-relations-versus-pointers][1])